# Prove that the set of extreme points of a compact convex set is not empty.

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, compactness, locally-convex-spaces

The Krein–Milman theorem states that if $S$ is convex and compact in a locally convex space, then $S$ is the closed convex hull of its extreme points. In particular, such a set has extreme points.

Is there a "simple argument" that the extreme points is not empty that avoids going through the full Krein-Milman theorem?

Comment: In the proof of the Krein-Milman theorem, one shows that a minimal extreme set of a compact convex set is a singleton. Whether one views that as a "simple argument" depends. If you're used to using the nonemptiness of a nested intersection of nonempty compact sets, and to Hahn-Banach arguments, it is simple. Otherwise, not so much.

Comment: Similar question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15654/extreme-point-compact-convex-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Daniel Fisher](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) comment as an answer.

In the proof of the Krein-Milman theorem, one shows that a minimal extreme set of a compact convex set is a singleton. Whether one views that as a "simple argument" depends. If you're used to using the nonemptiness of a nested intersection of nonempty compact sets, and to Hahn-Banach arguments, it is simple. Otherwise, not so much.